# Problems converting an array to a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a text file called Labyrint, that I read into a char array. After that I read the char array into a list without the \n (line break character). After I did that I convert the list to an array. Now I want this array to be a two dimensional array, but how do I do that. Here is an image of the labyrint that is 21x21 in size [Labyrint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhzs8.png). And below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[] FloridaArray;
        static string DenverString;
        static string[,] names = new string[21, 21];
        static List<object> wrd = new List<object>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Increase Console Buffer Height
            Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
            DenverString = ConvertStringArrayToString();
            FloridaArray = DenverString.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(DenverString);

            for (int i = 0; i < FloridaArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (FloridaArray[i] != '\n')
                {
                    wrd.Add(FloridaArray[i].ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (object o in wrd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }

            //Here I check what index 21 contain in the list called wrd
            Console.WriteLine("Here I check if index 21 contain character B:       " + wrd[21]);
            Console.WriteLine(wrd.GetType());

            // Here I convert the list called wrd to an array.
            object[] myArray = wrd.ToArray();
            // Here I check what character is in index 21 in the array called myArray.
            Console.WriteLine(myArray[21]);
            //Here I look up the data type of myArray
            Console.WriteLine(myArray.GetType());

            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
                {
                    // how do I put the value from my char array into the two dimensional array?
                    names[j, i] = myArray[i].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(j + " names " + i);    
                }
            }
        }

        static string ConvertStringArrayToString()
        {
            // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var value in File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
            {
                builder.Append(value);
                builder.Append('\n');
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the important point here is that your index into the main array needs to be calculated. From your nested loop indexers, the value you need is:

```
j*21 + i
```

So that makes you loop look like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
    {
        names[j, i] = myArray[j*21 + i].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(j + " names " + i);    
    }
}
```

You may need to adjust your indexes though, I cannot tell exactly as you haven't provided any example input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidG it solved the problem. The only thing I needed to change was 21 to 20 (cause I skipped 1 line when I was reading in the file) but I left myArray[ j * 21 + i] be as 21 else it would give me the wrong index. If you see this comment can't you explain why you multiply j with 21? That part I really don't understand ?